# Tried hard to get data from fetch api for a get request to http://swapi.co

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

I am trying hard to make a sucessful request to http://swapi.co.in from my localhost  creat-react-app project. 
I have put my fetch api request in my componentDidMount of main contianer.

```html
fetchData = () => {
        return fetch('http://swapi.co/api/people', {method: 'GET'}).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }
```

gives me a error of

```html
Failed to load http://swapi.co/api/people: Redirect from 'http://swapi.co/api/people' to 'https://swapi.co/api/people' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.


1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

After i upadted my fecth Data function to

```html
 fetchData = () => {
        return fetch('http://swapi.co/api/people', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            }

        }).then((response) => {

            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }
```

It gives a error

```html
Failed to load http://swapi.co/api/people: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
:3000/#/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I tried multiple configuration with mode: cors, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: origin , others . None of them worked for me.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: I am betting it is going from http to https for the redirect....

Comment: Try changing your fetch request from HTTP to HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why you are having issues with the HTTP request

The server sends the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 19:20:06 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 20:20:06 GMT
Location: https://swapi.co/api/people/
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 45299ce127d321b6-EWR
```

None of these are CORS headers, and as the request redirects, it requires CORS.

## How to fix

To fix this you can change HTTP for HTTPS, which avoids the redirect.

## Why doesn't adding the header yourself work

As the header is used to stop websites making requests the header has to be sent by the server. If the website could send this then the CORS protection wouldn't add anything.